# SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "*": syntax error

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am getting `SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "*": syntax error`in the below code while deleting row from table.Whats wrong with the code and why i am getting this error?

```
 public void deleteVideo(String key){
            String selectQuery = "DELETE  * FROM " + TABLE_TOW + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "= '"+key;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        }
```

Comment: In addition to the `*` error, you're also missing a `'` at the end. In general, string concatenation is a **very** poor way of writing SQL queries. It would be *particularly* bad practice if the `key` is in any way input by the end user (via a URL, for instance), as it leaves you wide open to SQL Injection attacks; [more](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: you are using wrong syntax.  you can use this too...  sqlitedb.delete(TaskDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null);

Answer (score 5):

It should be `"Delete from........"` and not `"Delete * from........"`. Because you have made a syntax issue

Comment: i want to delete complete row

Comment: Which is what delete from does. If you just wanted to clear certain fields that would be an update.

Comment: @user3684678 to delete whole row, my changes suggested will work

Comment: @user3684678: ***What*** error? Seriously, you need to make an effort here. Note my comment on the question about `'`.

Comment: try this  `String selectQuery = "DELETE   FROM " + TABLE_TOW + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "= '"+key+"'";`

Comment: I tried..  String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TOW  + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "='"+key+"'";  its not deleting row from table..not showing any error

Comment: @user3684678 can you confirm the key u are passing in the query is there in the table

Answer (score 2):

Pass value in `single quote (')` and remove `*` from query

### Final:

```
String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TOW + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "='"+key+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `*` from your query.

**Updated Code**

```
public void deleteVideo(String key){
    String selectQuery = "DELETE  FROM " + TABLE_TOW + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "= '"+key+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk isn't necessary with `DELETE`. In fact, it's invalid. The `DELETE FROM` function will delete the entire row. There is no way to specify which columns are to be deleted, because the clause can only delete entire rows.

You can't really 'delete' a cell. You can set to be empty (`''`), or `NULL`.

If you need to specifically edit the contents of certain columns I recommend the `UPDATE table SET a = 'b' WHERE id = 'some number'` clause